# shared parameters in dynamic model with ODE

Tags: r, ode

I am new in R programming and working on a dynamic model in R, but
facing a problem I can not figure out now. Appreciate any help or
suggestions. My data is like this:

```
data <- data.frame(time=c(60,75,90,105,120, 135, 
          150,165,180, 195,210,225,240,255,270,300), 
       A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0),  
       B=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),
       C=c(6,7,9,11,13,14,15,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8),
       D=c(5,6,7,8,11,12,14,13,12,10,6,5,3,3,2,1),
       E=c(3,4,5,6,7,8,8,6,5,4,4,3,2,2,1,1))

for(n in c(1:5) ){
  IR <- data[,1+n]
  time <- data[,1]
  d<-data.frame(time, IR)
  Mod<-function(t, parms){
  derivs<-function(t, state, parms){
    with(as.list(c(state, parms)),{
      I <- if(t>60 & t<165 ){I} else{0}
      dQ=k1+I-k*Q2
return(list(c(dQ)),IR=Q/2)
state<-c(Q=1)
return(ode(y=state, times=time, func=derivs, parms=parms, method ="rk4"))
pars<-c( k1=0.1,k=0.1)
Objective<-function(x, parset=names(x)){
    pars[parset]<-x
tout<-d$time
out<-Mod(tout,pars)
return(modCost(obs=d, model=out, weight="mean", method="Marq"))
  }
  lower = c(k1=0, k=0)
  upper=c( k1=10, k=10)
  m1<-modFit(p=pars, f=Objective,lower=lower, upper=upper)
  out1 <- data.frame(summary(m1)$par)
  out1$ID <- k
if(k==1){
    coefficients <- out1
  } else {
    coefficients <- rbind(coefficients, out1)
  }
}
```

My data is more complicated than above one, and I can not fit them one
by one, that is why I add for loop. By this way, I can fit parameters
k1 and k for each data set A,B, C,D E. But now I want to fit parameter
k just once cross data A, B,C,D,E. Is there any way I can do it in
this dynamic model?

Answer (score 0):

You can always append new values to existing objects returned by modCost via its argument "cost", e.g. in case you want to fit several data sets A, and B, this is what I would do (in pseudocode)

```
Objective <- function (x, ) {

....

out  <- Mod(tout,pars)  # pars applying to dataset A
Cost <- modCost(obs=A, model=out, weight="mean")

pars2 <- pars          # pars2 applies to dataset B, but same k
pars2["k1"] <- ...
out2 <- Mod(tout,pars2)  
Cost <- modCost(obs=B, model=out2, weight="mean", cost = Cost)   # Appends to existing object Cost

# and so on... for data sets C and D

return(Cost)
}
```

This way you do not need the overarching loop; you just run the model several times in the Objective function, each time using parameters specific for the different data sets and updating the model cost.

Hope it helps,

Karline

Comment: This is very helpful. I still have one question. So how can I use modFit() function to fit all parameters. I tried modFit(p=pars, f=Objective,lower=lower, upper=upper), but it only return back 2 parameters for first dataset A. Do you have any experience on this? Thank you!